# Get all QuickBooks Online accounts regardless of active status

Tags: vb.net, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to retrieve all the accounts from a company by using the `DataService.FindAll(...)` method but it only seems to be returning active accounts. Is there a way to get all the accounts regardless of the active status?

I know I've got inactive accounts because I purposely put them there to test and such.

My current line looks like this:

```
Dim accounts As List(Of Intuit.Ipp.Data.Account) = ds.FindAll(New Intuit.Ipp.Data.Account()).ToList()
```

I've also tried adding a `... With {.Active = False}...` in there too just to see if that would find all that are inactive. Still nothing.

Am I overlooking something or should this work and get me all accounts?

Thanks for any help.

Also, I'm using Intuit's .NET SDK with VB.NET.

Comment: Use IDSQuery operation in Dotnet. FindAll will not return the inactive records.

Comment: @nimishashrivastava So would I create a `QueryService(T)` object then just call the `ExecuteIdsQuery(...)` method, passing in my Query/SQL string, then just get the collection back? (If I'm understanding their SDK documentation, specifically I'm looking at [this](http://developer-static.intuit.com/SDKDocs/QBV3Doc/IPPDotNetDevKitV3/?topic=html/403ccdc5-60d0-0853-1728-851bfc911b0e.htm).)

Comment: QueryService<Account> AccQueryService = new QueryService<Account>(context);
List<Account> accs = AccQueryService.ExecuteIdsQuery("SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Active IN (True, False)").ToList();

Comment: You can also use lambda functions- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/query_filters

Comment: Ya, that's what I discovered. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this -

```
SELECT * FROM Account WHERE Active IN (true, false)
```

ApiExplorer - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO#Account

**JAVA Code**

```
Account account = GenerateQuery.createQueryEntity(Account.class);
String accountQuery = select($(account)).where($(account.isActive()).in(new Boolean[]{true, false})).generate();
service.executeQuery(accountQuery);
```

Thanks